# Sorbet - Unable to resolve constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

After running `srb init` and `srb tc` passing in a new Rails project, I installed RSpec and `srb tc` now has many complaints including:

```
spec/spec_helper.rb:16: Unable to resolve constant RSpec https://srb.help/5002
    16 |RSpec.configure do |config|
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Sorbet does not know about [anything defined in a gem](https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi) by default. It needs to generate an RBI file for the gem to understand the gem's constants and APIs.

When installing new gems you have to update the RBI files, which is easy with

```
srb rbi update
```

*Note: If this errors with `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - update`, change [this line](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/master/gems/sorbet/bin/srb-rbi#L76) in your local gem to use `STDIN.gets` instead of `Kernel.gets`. There are at least a [couple PRs](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1066/files) addressing [the issue](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1063) that as of this answer are not merged in.*

Comment: "This is because Sorbet does not know about anything defined in a gem by default." --
This is not true. Even though Sorbet doesn't know the types or typed signatures of methods in a gem, they generate the constants and available methods from [every gem in a repo](https://sorbet.org/docs/rbi#autogenerated-rbis-for-gems) and include them in `sorbet/gems` folder.

Comment: @hdoan that quote is directly from the Sorbet docs if you click the first link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an update here, `srb rbi` is deprecated in favor of `tapioca` (https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca)

`bundle exec tapioca init` should resolve these issues

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `srb init` does not finish properly. I have the RSpec module defined in `sorbet/gems/rspec-core.rbi` and a few other rspec gems rbi.

Do have a `sorbet/gems` folder? Does `srb rbi gems` work for you? If they don't, check out the Slack channel & ask about it there.

Edit: The issue is with gems installed after initial `srb init`. For those, you should run `srb rbi gems` to generate an RBI file for the added gems.

Comment: I think the issue was that I ran `srb init` first, `srb tc` passed, _then_ I installed RSpec and had to update the rbi with `srb rbi update` (which also runs `srb rbi gems`)

Comment: Ok. That'd explain it :-)